# translating static text

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have just built a view for one of my modules.
In there, I have this line; %
of Applicants Admitted`

I already installed modules like "Locale", "Content Translation" and "Internationalization" is already enabled.
But I dont understand how these modules will translate this text to other languages.
When I put it in `t('')` how will I know that it will translate it correctly. Can I manually enter the translation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translations have to be entered manually... always.  There is no "automatic machine translation" function provided by Drupal core or the Internationalization suite of modules.

Putting a string inside `t()` simply makes it available to Drupal's translation subsystem for translation; the string will still be displayed "as is" until it is translated manually.

To translate strings manually from the UI, if you have the Locale module enabled, you can go to the *Translate interface* page.  (On Drupal 7: `/admin/config/regional/translate/translate`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Patrick. What I dont get is, I put `quick stats` inside `t()` but I only get quick on the `translate interface` page. `<?php print t('quick stats'); ?>` itself

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?